# Using sweet alert with asp.net VB code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to create a pop-up for my asp.net program that waits for the response from a code behind function as to whether it fails or passes. I like how sweet alert looks so I am trying to implement their features but can't get it to work.

Here's what I have so far;

VB.NET

```
Sub Button_OnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(sender, GetType(), "Popup", "successalert();", True)
End Sub
```

ASPX

```
<asp:Button ID="Button"  OnClick="Button_OnClick" class="Block-Button" text="Create New Segment" runat="server"/>
```

I have also tried the following:

JS

```
function addAGroup(e) {
  swal({
    title: "Ajax request example",
    text: "Submit to run ajax request",
    type: "info",
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
    },
    function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            swal("Ajax request finished!");
        }, 2000);
  });
}
```

ASPX

```
<asp:Button ID="Button"  OnClientClick="(addAGroup())" class="Block-Button" text="Create New Group" runat="server"/>
```

Sorry if this is a simple thing, new to ASP.NET and completely clueless. Thanks

Comment: `OnClientClick="(addAGroup())"` should probably be `OnClientClick="addAGroup()"`. Try checking your browser's developer console for JavaScript errors when you try and run the code. If something is going wrong with the JavaScript part it will tell you, in much the same way as Visual Studio tells you there's an exception in the VB.NET part.

Comment: @ADyson it gets to the JS, as i put a break point on the `swal({` line, it just skips over the next part i guess? or maybe it's the post back and reloading the page as it seems the JS is reloaded when i press next on it